# How to automatically disable enable results for a Swift Playground

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

I am developing a Swift Playground for the Swift Student Challenge that uses ARKit and Vision. In app form the code works perfectly and uses about 350mb of RAM. When I bring the code to the Playground, as soon as I try to add a single SCNNode, the playground crashes and says there was an error running your code.

As soon as I turn off enable results though, it runs as well as in app form.

Rather than telling the user to turn off enable results which feels a bit incomplete and hacky, is there a way to turn it off automatically?

Comment: I have almost the exact same scenario. A answer or at least what is causing the issue would be awesome

Comment: @theParadox42 I just added the answer to fix below, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I can toss that disgusting "Turn off this switch" view lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue! In the Manifest.plist of the page set `PlaygroundLoggingMode` as a string to `Off`. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_playgrounds/structuring_content_for_swift_playgrounds/adding_a_page_to_a_playground_book